# HTML, JavaScript. How to display different information on the same popup window button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to know how can I display different infromation on the same popup windows?

I'm using this example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal

I find out to make few same button active I have to edit JavaScript code, convert buttons into classes.

```html
<button class="myBtn">butoon 1</button>
<button class="myBtn">button 2</button>
<button class="myBtn">button 3</button>
```

JavaScript:

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
      btns[i].onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
      }
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
      }
}
```

But if I create few same buttons and change information in it I get the same information like in the first popup window. How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you share your code of modal? So that we can test your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

It works well for me.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

var modalText = document.getElementById('modal-text');

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].onclick = function(event) {
    switch(event.target.innerHTML) {
        case "button 1":
            modalText.innerHTML = "First button Clicked";
            break;
        case "button 2":
            modalText.innerHTML = "Second button Clicked";
            break;
        default:
            modalText.innerHTML = "Third button Clicked";
    }
    modal.style.display = "block";
  }
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button class="myBtn">button 1</button>
<button class="myBtn">button 2</button>
<button class="myBtn">button 3</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p id="modal-text">Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```